# How to populate checkbox from database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have saved value of checkbox in database, now I want to populate these value into checkbox. 
Let say, I want to checkbox checked or unchecked according to value in database.

```
If rowe(0).Item("offer_1").Value.ToString = "Yes" Then
                Offer_1CheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
            ElseIf rowe(0).Item("offer_1").Value.ToString = "No" Then
                Offer_1CheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
            End If

            If rowe(0).Item("offer_2").Value.ToString = "Yes" Then
                Offer_2CheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
            ElseIf rowe(0).Item("offer_2").Value.ToString = "No" Then
                Offer_2CheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
            End If
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Problem is that this code not run correctly and populate checkbox.

Comment: What you mean by "not running correctly"? Are you getting an exception? Checkbox remain unchecked? or else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not any database exception , you can use below
You dont need any if statements and you should use **Checked** property

```
Offer_1CheckBox.Checked = rowe(0).Item("offer_1").Value.ToString = "Yes"
Offer_2CheckBox.Checked = rowe(0).Item("offer_2").Value.ToString = "Yes"
```